# repeatedly create object by singleton but the object address is different

Tags: swift3, singleton

this is my code:

```
class Test {
    static let sharedInstance = Test()
    private init() {}
}

var obj1 = Test.sharedInstance
var obj2 = Test.sharedInstance

withUnsafePointer(to: &obj1) {
    print(" obj1 value \(obj1) has address: \($0)")
}

withUnsafePointer(to: &obj2) {
    print(" obj2 value \(obj2) has address: \($0)")
}
```

Log:

obj1 value Test has address: 0x0000000112cc5bf8

obj2 value Test has address: 0x0000000112cc5c00

Thanks in advance！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is showing the addresses of two variable, `obj1` and `obj2`.

```
import Foundation

class Test {
    static let sharedInstance = Test()
    init() {} //Make initializer accessible for testing.
}

var obj1 = Test.sharedInstance
var obj2 = Test.sharedInstance

withUnsafePointer(to: &obj1) {
    print(" var obj1 is located at address: \($0)")
}
withUnsafePointer(to: &obj2) {
    print(" var obj2 is located at address: \($0)")
}
obj2 = Test() //Create new instance.
withUnsafePointer(to: &obj2) {
    print(" var obj2 is still located at address: \($0)")
}
```

output:

```
 var obj1 is located at address: 0x00000001003e4398
 var obj2 is located at address: 0x00000001003e43a0
 var obj2 is still located at address: 0x00000001003e43a0
```

If you want to compare the contained references in `obj1` and `obj2`, using `ObjectIdentifier` would be a simple way:

```
obj2 = Test.sharedInstance
print(" ObjectIdentifier of obj1 is \(ObjectIdentifier(obj1))")
print(" ObjectIdentifier of obj2 is \(ObjectIdentifier(obj2))")
obj2 = Test()
print(" ObjectIdentifier of obj2 is now \(ObjectIdentifier(obj2))")
```

output:

```
 ObjectIdentifier of obj1 is ObjectIdentifier(0x0000000100e04a80)
 ObjectIdentifier of obj2 is ObjectIdentifier(0x0000000100e04a80)
 ObjectIdentifier of obj2 is now ObjectIdentifier(0x0000000100e075f0)
```

Or, you can convert the references to OpaquePointers and then to Ints like this:

```
let addrInt1 = Int(bitPattern: Unmanaged.passRetained(obj1).toOpaque())
print("Address of obj1 = \(String(format: "%016lX", addrInt1))")
let addrInt2 = Int(bitPattern: Unmanaged.passRetained(obj2).toOpaque())
print("Address of obj2 = \(String(format: "%016lX", addrInt2))")
```

output:

```
Address of obj1 = 0000000100E04A50
Address of obj2 = 0000000100E049E0
```

Comment: I got it,Thank you very much!